# Storing the access token and the status response in React Native

Tags: api, react-native, authentication, access-token

So I am trying to get the status of the response and check if it was 200 and then I want to store the access token in a global variable.

```
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((responsejson) => {
    alert(responsejson.access_token);
    console.log(response.text());
})
```

In the above sample code I can access the `access_token` , but if I want the `response.status` so I can check its value I get undefined, so how can I get access for this two value without getting undefined?

```
.then((response) => {
   console.log(text2);
   if (response.status == 200) {
}
```

Here I can get the `response.status` and the `access_token` will be undefined.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to parse the response into json format after the status checking ?

```
.then((response) => {
   if (response.status == 200) {
       response.json().then((responsejson) => {
           alert(responsejson.access_token);             
       })
});
```

If you have acces to the status in the second block and to the token on the first block, why don't you just mix both of them ?

Comment: you know that moment in life when you fell so stupid for not think of something so simple, that is how I fell now :<,but thank you for the help